# Serializing the object in jdk 1.5 and deserializing it jdk 1.6

Tags: java

I was plannnig to do a research , please advise if I try to mix java 1.5 and 1.6. For e.g I have a java 1.5  and I have serialized a java object in a file in  c:\ drive  and then and then tried opening in java 1.6 will there be any exception and if I do vice versa of it..?

Comment: That is easy to test by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serialization mechanism itself has not changed. For individual classes it will depend on the specific class. If a class has a serialVersionUID field, this is supposed to indicate serialization compatiblity.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7287480476309918049L;
If it is unchanged, the serialized versions are compatible.
```

Comment: `serialVersionUID` refers to compatibility of different versions of the class, and doesn't actually indicate anything about the version of Java used for serialization. You could serialize an instance of the class under both Java 5 and 6, but the `serialVersionUID` wouldn't change.